# How to display a rendered Handlebars template in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, handlebars.js

I'd like to display a rendered Handlebars template in an iframe, for various reasons (isolated css, easy loading of assets, etc.). I'll be doing this in Javascript. How can I do this?

I've tried the following:

1. Appending an `iframe` element with the `src` set to the Handlebars document, then using jQuery/Handlebars to grab the contents of the `body`, compiling it, and putting it back in the `iframe`.

   - The problem here is that the DOM is different from the static `.hbs` file, and I'd prefer to use the raw `hbs` file. For example, some scripts could be injected, and this tends to screw things up.
2. Appending an `iframe` element with the `src` set to `about:blank`, making an `ajax` request for the Handlebars document, compiling it, then appending it to the `iframe`'s body.

   - The problem here is that the assets use the `iframe`'s `src` attribute when fetching resources from the  server, and since it's not set, the resources cannot be located. If I change the `src` after I do this step, the whole `iframe` reloads.

Answer (score 1):

This article on Blobs/Bloburls might help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

This is basically how it could work:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');

// Create a new Blob using your data and handlebars template
var blob = new Blob(['<div>Hello World</div>'], {type : 'text/html'});

// create a URL from your new blob
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Set your iframe to show the Bloburl
iframe.src = url;
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/83PQs/ )

Support for this is Chrome, SF, FF and IE10 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls).